# How to make an Azure Logic App parse different JSON messages

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a few Azure Logic Apps which all have the same structure: run on HTTP trigger > call stored procedure > parse JSON data > call REST API per record from sp.

The only difference between the apps is the name of the stored procedure and the fields in the result set.

I'd like to create a single Logic App (variable param in HTTP call to define which sp to execute), but I got stuck in the parse JSON step as it needs a fixed schema.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried such as the JSON Schema that you have tried as of now.

Comment: In this case I did not really try something because meaningful as I don't know where to start. AFAIK the Parse JSON step needs a schema. And exactly that schema is variable as the result set varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of Parse_JSON is to retrieve the variable inside the the JSON. If the JSON Schema is going to vary you can either make a combined JSON Schema which satisfies all the conditions of the flow or you can create parallel branches and have the schemas of its own.

Here is a screenshot on how we can add a parallel branch.  [image]

One of the best way to write the schema is to take the previous step's JSON and add it i the `Use Sample Payload to Generate Schema` so that it will automatically generates a Schema for the flow.

Here is my Logic App

[image]

while having the schema at `Parse JSON` I'm using the `Insert Row` JSON and using it in `Parse JSON`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Made one generic JSON schema that covered all possible attributes. For who's using this approach too: when generating the schema based on a payload, remove elements in the _required_ section of the generated scheme.